# Lottie Animation Drawable Renders Incorrectly Inside a Floating Action Button on Android 5

Tags: android, kotlin, floating-action-button, lottie

I'm trying to set an `LottieDrawable` as image drawable for a `FloatingActionButton`. The problem comes when I try to run the code on an Android 5 device: the animation is not centered within the button as it is in Android >= 6.
Anyone has an answer for this problem or maybe an workaround?

```
val lottieDrawable = LottieDrawable()

LottieCompositionFactory.fromRawRes(context, R.raw.loading_anim).addListener { lottieComposition ->
     lottieDrawable.composition = lottieComposition
     lottieDrawable.scale = 0.5F
     lottieDrawable.repeatCount = LottieDrawable.INFINITE
     lottieDrawable.playAnimation()
}

floatingActionButton.setImageDrawable(lottieDrawable)
```

Expected result (Android 6,7,8,9,Q):

### [image: Expected Result (Android 6,7,8,9,Q)[1]

Actual Result (Android 5) 
[image: Actual Result (Android 5)]

Comment: I have the same bug using `Lottie` in a normal `LottieAnimationView`, looks like Lottie lost the padding on Android 5. Looking for a fix too

Comment: May I know what Lottie version are you using?